# What is wrong with my account?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I logged in initially with my Facebook account in Stackoverflow. Then I created several accounts in StackExchange sites. Today I was casually visiting data.SE and wanted to login. but there was no arrangement to use Facebook credential. so I used rather my Google account to login and to my surprise I found I have logged in as [John.doe10225](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/10224/jon-doe10225). My avatar is still the same. But in other sites when I logged in it came as [Mistu4u](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/3271/mistu4u). This is the first time I got different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking with some people that know more than I do on this issue, the data site **is not part of the SE network** on a technical side.

However, because it still uses Gravatar and your e-mail is associated with both accounts, that is why you have your Gravatar on that site.